# Can I use this keyboard with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: keyboard

I am wondering if it is possible to use this keyboard with a raspberry pi b+, I soldered the USB cable to the receiver but is not detected on a windows computer, thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get any USB keyboard working with your other computer, then it should work with Raspberry Pi.

Check your USB cable color coding. Green is usually D+. To test, use a multi-meter between your type A connector and the end of the green wire. With the end of the plug facing you and the contacts facing up, D+ will be on the left and D- on the right. See [Pinouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Pinouts) for more.

When you connect the receiver to a computer, a new HID keyboard should be detected. On Windows, check the Device Manager. In Linux, try `sudo dmesg -w` to watch for new connections or `lsusb` to list existing USB connections. If connecting the receiver does not provide a new device, then the problem is with the receiver.

If your operating system has detected the receiver device, then check the keyboard. Make sure the batteries are good and that the transmitter LED has direct line of sight with the IR receiver. You can also test the transmitter by using a smartphone camera to look at the IR LED while pushing buttons on the keyboard. You should see the LED light up through an average smartphone camera app.

If all of this looks good but you are still not getting keyboard input, then make sure that the receiver is matched to keyboard. If they are not matched, then the IR protocol sent by the transmitter may not be compatible with the receiver.

Comment: the receiver is not IR based

Comment: I had the white cable on D+, that solved the issue, thank you.

Comment: This keyboard doesn't have a Tab key. Do you know how I can map that key instead of  mute?

Comment: @jsotola, ahh, you are right. I see the trace antenna now. I just saw the big IR looking LED on the bottom side of the keyboard and assumed.

Comment: @bran, It's probably best to create a new question about remapping keys so other people can benefit from the discussion. It is very likely to be possible.

Comment: @bram please do not ask new questions inside of comments ... as Kenny said, post a separate question ... your question about remapping keys on a linux computer will probably be a duplicate ... do research before asking

Comment: Alright, I'm new here. I'll go ahead and create a new question. Thanks!